# How to test if something has not been touched after a circle has been drawn

Tags: java, android, math, canvas, android-view

I have an app that draws random circles to the screen one after another. These circles colors are also random either green or red. If you are to click a red one you loose the game if you are to click a green one you get points. What I am trying to do is add a boolean that checks if someone has not clicked on a green circle or has not clicked the screen at all when a green circle is displayed. If a red circle is displayed and the user does not click anywhere nothing happens, but in the event that a green circle is displayed and nothing is clicked the user should be redirected to another class and loose all of there points. I have tried to make a boolean called isTouched and gave it the value false then placed it all throughout my code but nothing seems to work. Here is my code if the isTouched boolean is to equal false.

```
if(isTouched == false){
            howManyPoints = addPoints;
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
            lastColor = redColor;
            addPoints = 0;
            Intent i = new Intent(this.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
            this.getContext().startActivity(i);

        }
```

and here is the entire class.

```
public class DrawingView extends View{



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;
    public static int savedScore;
    public static List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String[] savedScores = new String[a.size()];
    Paint red;
    public static int howManyPoints;
    boolean isTouched;

    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            if(addPoints < 10){
                handler.postDelayed(this, 700);
            }
            if(addPoints > 9 && addPoints < 30){
                handler.postDelayed(this,550);
            }
            if(addPoints > 29){
                handler.postDelayed(this, 450);
            }
            postInvalidate();
        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);

    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        Paint back = new Paint();
        back.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rect background = new Rect();
        background.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight() );
        canvas.drawRect(background, back);

        Paint newPaint = new Paint();
        newPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        newPaint.setTextSize(60);
        canvas.drawText("ALPHA 1.64.5", 10, 60, newPaint);



        if(random == null){
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight, radius, paint);

        red = new Paint();
        red.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        red.setTextSize(150);
        canvas.drawText("" + addPoints, 500, 1350, red);


    }



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
                if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
                    //Do your things here
                        if(lastColor == redColor){
                            //saveScore();
                            howManyPoints = addPoints;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
                            lastColor = redColor;
                            addPoints = 0;
                            Intent i = new Intent(this.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
                            this.getContext().startActivity(i);

                        } 
                        if(lastColor == greenColor){
                            addPoints++;
                            isTouched = true;

                        }
                }else  {

                }

        }
        if(isTouched == false){
            howManyPoints = addPoints;
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
            lastColor = redColor;
            addPoints = 0;
            Intent i = new Intent(this.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
            this.getContext().startActivity(i);

        }
        return false;

}

public void saveScore() {
        a.add("" + addPoints);
        //if(Integer.parseInt(savedScores[1]) < addPoints){
            //savedScores[2] = savedScores[1];
            //int x = Integer.parseInt(savedScores[1]);
            //x = addPoints;
        //}
    }

public boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if ((((x - randomWidth)*(x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight)*(y - randomHeight))) < ((radius)*(radius))){
    return true;
  }
  return false;    
}

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as C++? *sigh*

Comment: java and c are pretty close

Comment: Where, on the keyboard?

Comment: @PaulTrueman That is not a valid excuse. If you are programming in Java, don't tag C++. Thanks. (I removed the C++ tag)

Comment: i will remove it myself